# Showing JavaScript alert before JSP forward

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to alert a message in javascript inside the body of a jsp page before a forward is performed and its not getting executed.

Here's the code

```
<%
...
out.write("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
out.write("alert( " + "' Hello '" + ");\n");
out.write("</script>\n");

request.getRequestDispatcher("secondpage.jsp").forward(request, response);
%>
```

Here I want to alert the message before I pass the control to another jsp page.How can I do this.
Here if i remove the forwarding part the alert message gets displayed in an alert box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `forward` replaces the content of the page, which is not sent to the browser.

As the browser doesn't even receive the script you write, it can't execute it.

Supposing you'd want the user to see the alert one second before being redirected, you could do this :

```
<%
out.write("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
out.write("alert(' Hello ');\n");
out.write("setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='secondpage.jsp'},1000);");
out.write("</script>\n");
%>
```

Comment: Any other way to achieve this.

Comment: use window.location since document.location is deprecated

Comment: @mplungjan I prefer indeed window.location, which is more logical, so I'll change it.

Comment: tried this the message gets displayed now but the control does not go to secondpage.jsp

Comment: JS code is executed line by line. You don't need a timeout at all. The alert function would block the next JS line from executing until the alert is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you writing JS code via Java *scriptlets* in JSP while JSP itself already offers an excellent template to write HTML/JS code plain in?

Anyway, just use JS to perform a redirect instead of JSP. You know, Java/JSP runs on webserver and produces HTML/JS which in turn runs in webbrowser only. A forward basically replaces the request/response destination and if the response is uncommitted, it discards everything which is written to the response buffer beforehand.

Here's how you could do it with in normal HTML/JS:

```
<script>
    alert('Hello');
    window.location = 'secondpage.jsp';
</script>
```

That's it. See, you don't need to put it in some *scriptlet* ugliness at all. Just put it in its entirety in the JSP file.

Comment: except not using timeout breaks the back button. So a .replace is preferable if you do not do a timeout

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I was writing JS code via java scriplets as i wanted to access some java content to be alerted in the JS. Is there an alternative for this too.

Comment: Just use EL. E.g. `alert('${bean.property}')`.